# Building Android project to different packages

Tags: android, ant, build-automation

I'm trying to find the best way to build/package an Android app for 6+ different customers. I could use different branches in SVN for all of the customers, but the only difference between the apps are some values in the resource folder (drawables, strings, etc).

I wrote an ant script that imports the standard Android **build.xml**. This script does the following:

1. Reads the customer names from a properties file.
2. For each customer the following is done:

   1. The package name in **AndroidManifest.xml** is changed (by hooking into the **-pre-build** target).
   2. The custom resources are copied into the **res** directory in the build (by hooking into the **-pre-compile** target).
   3. The package name is changed back to the default value (by hooking into the **-post-compile** target).
   4. The APK is copied to a specific location an named something like **customer-versionno.apk**.

This seemed to work well until I just now wrote the part that changes the package name. Because of the package name change the location of the **R** class is also changed, meaning that the build fails as the Java classes import the **R** class from the standard package.

I don't want to have a build script that changes code. I want to be able to do this with minimum changes to any files.

Soo..the questions are really:

1. Are there any good/simple solutions for my problem?
2. Am I approaching this problem in the wrong way? Are there better ways to easily package the same app to 6+ different customers?

Comment: How about the 'External Definition'?

Comment: @lulumeya I'm not sure if I know what you mean..?

Comment: Alternatively, this is quite easy to achieve by Maven. Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371698/speeding-up-the-android-build-process/9372333#9372333).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to solve this with making 6+ different projects that includes your main projekt. This way you are able to override resources and make different apk's

Comment: This is indeed possible. And all the customer projects would not need much attention/work. However, I would like being able to have a one click build and not having that many projects in my IDE just for a relatively small app.

Comment: Looking back at this today I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to change the package name? Changing the package name is a pain to do automatically. That being said, here is my solution to the problem:

My scenario is that I have one app that gets deployed to 30-200 different signed APK files where the only difference between the files are some resources (drawables, strings, values etc), and the package name.

I do this by working on a generic version of the app that serves as the template project. Once this works and I am ready to deploy I invoke a bash script that loops through the following steps for each target:

1. Clean the project completely
2. Swap out res dir and package name using sed.
3. Builds and signs the APK

This balances the horrific deply time with fast developemnt time. I really don't see another more elegant/robust solution than this.

And finally a small tip: In android manifest use relative package names like ".Application" instead of "com.mycompany.myproject.Application". This way you only need to change the package name in ONE location.

Comment: If you are not into bash I would suggest using a scriptable build tool such as SBT (which also have a plugin for ANT). Then you can script the hold build process using Scala.