# choosing res directory at build time android

Tags: android, build

I want to create a build time switch res directory project,for which each resource folder having image/icons with same name but different image/icons.

for example:
res1>having abc.png of pink color
res2>having abc.png of orange color

First is this possible?
Is there any way to choose this at build time?
or ant build easy tutorial
or any other way....

Comment: no its not possible. R.java file wont create at runtime.

Comment: any other way to handle this situation??

Comment: keep only one folder and naming to your resources as abc1.png and abc2.png thru program you can change it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to do it at runtime dynamically. Unless you rename the res folder yourself before building the application :S

Comment: I have been provided with two separate res folders,and I require to build differnt apk using that.

Comment: Rename res1 to res, build your APK, then rename res2 to res and build your APK again. You should then have two APK, one with orange images the other with pink images.

Comment: It is possible if you adopt some command-line tools like Ant or Maven dominate build process. If using Maven, it is pretty easy, example case study [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699485/skinning-android-app-with-maven-build-profiles) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371698/speeding-up-the-android-build-process/9372333#9372333).